# Add hyphen to textarea when pressed enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, textarea

So I want to put hyphen to every new line on my textarea. How can I achieve this? I basically want it to look like this:

```
 - One
 - Two
 ...
```

Something with jQuery maybe but I have no idea what..

Comment: you just want to add a - to every text area?

Comment: No. I have 1 textarea and I want to add - to every new line in that textarea. So if user presses enter and it goes to new line that line should have -.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. i think this is  better

```js
$('#textbox').keypress(function(event){
 
 var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
 if(keycode == '13'){
  //alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox'); 
      
        var cursorPos = $('#textbox').prop('selectionStart');
            var v = $('#textbox').val();
            var textBefore = v.substring(0,  cursorPos );
            var textAfter  = v.substring( cursorPos, v.length );
            $('#textbox').val( textBefore+ "\n-" +textAfter );
        
        
        setCaretPosition(document.getElementById('textbox'),( cursorPos + 2));
        
        return false;
        
 }
 event.stopPropagation();
});

 function setCaretPosition(ctrl, pos){
 if(ctrl.setSelectionRange)
 {
  ctrl.focus();
  ctrl.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);
 }
 else if (ctrl.createTextRange) {
  var range = ctrl.createTextRange();
  range.collapse(true);
  range.moveEnd('character', pos);
  range.moveStart('character', pos);
  range.select();
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textbox"></textarea>
```

Comment: I ended up using this. Works perfectly for me because I can add new lines between existing ones. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jQuery Entey key capture event. Below fiddle will help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/666ausss/

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/666ausss/1/

```
$('#textbox').keypress(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox');  
        document.getElementById('textbox').value = document.getElementById('textbox').value + "\n-";
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This works almost perfectly. However now when I press enter it jumps two lines. First line has that "-" and second line where cursor jumps is empty. How can I keep the cursor on same line as "-" ?

Answer (score 0):

Please add this script . It will simply work.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('myTextarea').onkeyup = function(e) {

if (e.keyCode == 13){
  var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
  document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = x+'-';
    return false;
 }
}
</script>
```